# how to define a color for an instance of a class in Java Scipt

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web-deployment, game-physics

I've making a breakout game and I had to make some blocks and give them random colors defined in a array, but for making more blocks I had to use a for loop. So, when I add them to my update function, colors are flashing at frame rate. I think you'll understand better if you run the snippet

> one more thing: that canvasRendering...rundedRectangle is a function that draws rounded edge rectangles someone please find a solution!

```js
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundedRectangle = function(x, y, width, height, rounded) {
    const radiansInCircle = 2 * Math.PI;
    const halfRadians = (2 * Math.PI)/2;
    const quarterRadians = (2 * Math.PI)/4  ;
    
    // top left arc
    this.arc(rounded + x, rounded + y, rounded, -quarterRadians, halfRadians, true);
    
    // line from top left to bottom left
    this.lineTo(x, y + height - rounded);
  
    // bottom left arc  
    this.arc(rounded + x, height - rounded + y, rounded, halfRadians, quarterRadians, true)  ;
    
    // line from bottom left to bottom right
    this.lineTo(x + width - rounded, y + height);
  
    // bottom right arc
    this.arc(x + width - rounded, y + height - rounded, rounded, quarterRadians, 0, true)  ;
    
    // line from bottom right to top right
    this.lineTo(x + width, y + rounded)  ;
  
    // top right arc
    this.arc(x + width - rounded, y + rounded, rounded, 0, -quarterRadians, true)  ;
    // line from top right to top left
    this.lineTo(x + rounded, y)  ;
};

var canvas= document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function Player(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.show = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffff";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
    this.move = function(speed){
        this.x += speed;
    };
}

function Ball(x,y,r){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.show = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,2* Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "tomato";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
    this.move= function(speedX,speedY){
        this.show();
        this.speed = 2;
        this.x += speedX;
        this.y += speedY;
    };

}

var colors = ['#A5E75A','#7254AD','#FFD606','#FF093D'];
function Block(x,y,w,h){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.status =1;
    this.show= function(color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.roundedRectangle(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h,5);
        //ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,10,0,2*Math.PI);
        //ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    };
}

var player = new Player(canvas.width/2-50,780,100,20);
var ball = new Ball(player.x+player.w/2, player.y,15);


var rigthPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

var blocks = [];
var rowCount = 5;
var columnCount = 6;
var noInRow = 6;
var blockCount = (rowCount*columnCount)+1;
var rc = {blockRow : 0,
    blockCol : 0};


for(let i = 0; i < blockCount; i++){
    blocks.push(new Block(rc.blockCol*60+25,rc.blockRow*60-30,50,50)); 
    rc.blockCol++;
    if(i % noInRow === 0){
        rc.blockRow++;
        rc.blockCol = 0;
    }
}


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        rigthPressed = true;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = true;
    }
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 39){
        rigthPressed = false;
    }
    if(e.keyCode == 37){
        leftPressed = false;
    }
});

function objMovement(){
    if(rigthPressed){
        player.move(5);
        if (player.x > canvas.width-player.w){
            player.x = canvas.width-player.w;
        }
    }
    if(leftPressed){
        player.move(-5);
        if(player.x < 0){
            player.x = 0;
        }
    }

    if(ball.x > canvas.width-ball.r || ball.x < 0+ball.r){
        ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
    }
    if (/*ball.y > canvas.height-ball.r ||*/ball.y < 0+ball.r){
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
    }
    if(ball.x<player.x+player.w &&ball.x>player.x && ball.y>player.y && ball.y<player.y+player.h){
        ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        ballSpeedX= ballSpeedX;
    }
    function Bump(){
        if (ball.x>player.x && ball.x<player.x+player.w/2){
            if (ball.y >= player.y){
                ballSpeedX = -5;
            }
        }
        if(ball.x>player.x+player.w/2 && ball.x<player.x+player.w){
            if(ball.y >= player.y){
                ballSpeedX = 5;
            }
        }
    }   
    //Bump();
}

function reload(){
    if (ball.y>canvas.height){
        //alert('gameOver');
        ball.x =player.x+player.w/2;
        ball.y = player.y-ball.r;
        ballSpeedX = 0;
        ballSpeedY = 0;
    }
}

var ballSpeedX = 0;
var ballSpeedY = -0;

function collision(){
    for(let i=1;i<blockCount;i++){
        if(ball.x>blocks[i].x && 
            ball.x<blocks[i].x+blocks[i].w && 
            ball.y>blocks[i].y && 
            ball.y<blocks[i].y+blocks[i].h){
            blocks[i].status = 0;
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
            blocks.splice(i,1);
            blockCount--;
            //ballSpeedX = 0;
            //ballSpeedY = 0;
            console.log('hit');
    
        }
    } 
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    objMovement();
    for(let i=1;i<blockCount;i++){  
        if(blocks[i].status == 1){
            blocks[i].show(colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
        }
    }
    collision();
    ball.show();
    ball.move(ballSpeedX,ballSpeedY);
    player.show();
    reload();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #body{
            background-color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
        }
        #gameCanvas{
            border: 15px solid rgb(44, 44, 44);
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-color:rgb(19, 18, 18);
            margin: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width=400 height=800></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you remove and redraw all rectangles from the canvas each update and assign a new color on show, they get assigned a new color each update. You might be able to avert this by adding a property `color` to the rectangle, which is initialised (once, so in the initial for loop) with a random color, and alter the `show` function to use `this.color` rather than accept a color as an argument. This way, you don't assign a new color to a rectangle each update, and it won't change color each update.